# Get File Path using File name from a TextBox in C#

Tags: c#, html, .net, filepath

I'm using `input type = file` and I'm using Chrome so I would **not** be allowed to get the file path of the file chosen. It only gives back the **file name**.

This is my existing code:

```
string path = Path.GetFullPath(appPerfLog.Value);
```

I was expecting this result so that I could use the full Path in my app:

```
C:\Users\myUsername\Desktop\someFolder\Proactive_Hiring_VW101582_Combo_200users_09210316.csv
```

But this is what I get instead:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\Proactive_Hiring_VW101582_Combo_200users_09210316.csv
```

How can I get the **full path** by searching the directories in my computer? I need to use it for StreamReader. Google Chrome only returns the `file name` due to security concerns so I need help on knowing a workaround/alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as a full path to an uploaded file, or at least, not one you ought to be using.

When you upload a file to a web server, the web framework you use stores this file either in memory or on disk in a temporary directory, and from there, it is made accessible to your application as a stream to read it once, or with a method to save it to a directory of your choice.

What you're trying to do is not going to fly once your application is deployed on a web server, because there is no guarantee that the file is even going to be present with the name it used to have on the client. For all you know, the file named `D:\Temp\Foo.txt` at the client is named `C:\Windows\Temp\asdfg123.tmp` on the server.

You will need to use the appropriate APIs for the web application framework you're using. For an ASP.NET FileUpload control, you're going to have to use [`FileUpload.SaveAs(string filename)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.saveas(v=vs.110).aspx) to let ASP.NET write the file to a path of your choosing. After that, you can use the `filename` to read the file from your code.

Comment: In other words, I just have to abandon `input type = file` and use **FileUpload** control instead? Just for clarification. @CodeCaster

Comment: No, I'm telling you need to use the proper API. You can just use a file input, but then how you process the file depends on how you read it in the first place. If that is through `Request.Files[]`, then that returns an `HttpPostedFile`, which also has a `SaveAs()` method.

Comment: To clarify, I do **not** need to upload the file to the web server. I need the full path to read the CSV file and perform calculations on its values for the result. Is there a solution for that? Thanks!

Comment: You cannot access files on the client from the web server, so you **do** need to upload the file.

Comment: I will try to follow your suggestions. Thank you very much, @CodeCaster ! :)